# Stringify a multi-dimension array with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web, stringify

Im creating an invoice for books, and aim to submit it via ajax. Im trying to json encode the array of books in the invoice, however I keep getting a blank value

```
 //create item list
    var order_items = [];
    $('#mi_books tbody tr.userbooks').each(function(index)
    {
        var bookisbn = $(this).find('td .mi_isbn').text();

        var bookdata = [];
        bookdata['isbn'] = bookisbn;
        bookdata['title'] = $(this).find('.mi_title').text();
        bookdata['qty'] = $(this).find('.mi_qty').text();
        bookdata['price'] = $(this).find('.mi_price').text();

        order_items.push(bookdata);

    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(order_items));
    alert(order_items.toString());
    console.log(order_items);
```

`alert(JSON.stringify(order_items));`
Outputs: `[[]]`

`alert(order_items.toString());`
Outputs:  `blank`

`console.log(order_items);`
Output:

```
Array[1]
0: Array[0]
isbn: "9781401216672"
length: 0
price: "1007"
qty: "1"
title: "Batman: The Killing Joke"
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

My array is being created, but somehow I cant seem to json encode it? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try

```
var order_items = {};
$('#mi_books tbody tr.userbooks').each(function(index)
{
    var bookisbn = $(this).find('td .mi_isbn').text();

    var bookdata = {
      'isbn': bookisbn,
      'title': $(this).find('.mi_title').text(),
      'qty': $(this).find('.mi_qty').text(),
      'price': $(this).find('.mi_price').text()
    };
    order_items[index] = bookdata;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(order_items));
```

your only mistake was a try to create associative arrays instead of using objects, that can do it

Comment: just tell why are you downvoting

Comment: Your code works perfectly! Thanks!
Im assuming your post was downvoted simply because I asked 'what i was doing wrong', not for the code itself :)

Answer (score 4):

`Array` and `Object` are different beasts. Your `bookdata` is not an array, but an object, thus, you should create it with

`var bookdata = {};`

Comment: And, for readability, assign with `bookdata.isbn = ...` instead of square brackets and strings (it is the same, by definition, in ES5 spec).

Comment: See also @Jack's answer below, you could bind creation of empty `{}` with filling it as shown there (I would probably do it, too, as a second step; I fixed the immediate bug).

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I assumed bookdata was also an array because the console.log output said 'array'

Comment: @pinkpixycoder Yes, it was an array, you created it as such: `[]`. The variable will hold what you put to it, empty array `[]`, empty object `{}` or whatever else.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are serialized differently with `JSON.stringify()` as opposed to regular objects (only properties of UInt32 are serialized). Since you're only adding textual properties to the `bookdata`, you should use anonymous objects like this:

```
var bookdata = {
    isbn: bookisbn,
    title: $(this).find('.mi_title').text(),
    qty: $(this).find('.mi_qty').text(),
    price: $(this).find('.mi_price').text()
};
```